# SQL select not load rows with certain value in them

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL select not load rows with a certain value in them, not to load the ID if values contain "Red" in the Value field

INPUT

```
ID  Row ID  Value
--------------------
1   4234    Red
1   4543    Blue
1   4852    Green
2   5161    Blue
2   5470    Green
3   5779    Red
3   6088    Green
4   6397    Red
5   6706    Green
5   7015    Blue
```

OUTPUT

```
ID  Row ID  Value
------------------
2   5161    Blue
2   5470    Green
5   6706    Green
5   7015    Blue
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB29Q.jpg)

Comment: show us your query.

Comment: Select  
Cust_ID,
Row_ID,
Value
From Cust.dbo where Value <> Red

Comment: Red needs to be in quotes in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Set Operators - EXCEPT and INTERSECT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
 as shown below.

```
create table MyTable(ID int, [Row ID] int,  Value varchar(20))
insert into MyTable Values
(1, 4234, 'Red'),
(1, 4543, 'Blue'),
(1, 4852, 'Green'),
(2, 5161, 'Blue'),
(2, 5470, 'Green'),
(3, 5779, 'Red'),
(3, 6088, 'Green'),
(4, 6397, 'Red'),
(5, 6706, 'Green'),
(5, 7015, 'Blue')

 Select MyTable.* from (Select id from MyTable 
 except
 select id from MyTable where Value = 'Red'
 )a inner join MyTable on a.Id = MyTable.Id
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a3a46ccb19493c9f58fbc5fb9bc3cb4) demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries

```
Select * from tblColor where ID not in(Select Id from tblColor where Value = 'Red')
```

Comment: Sorry getting an error  (ERROR: Subquery has too many columns)

`Select distinct
B.Cust_ID,
A.Row_ID,
A.Value
From Cust.dbo A
Left Join CustOrd.dbo B where B.Cust_ID not in (Select distinct
B.Cust_ID,
A.Row_ID,
A.Value
From Cust.dbo A
Left Join CustOrd.dbo B where A.Value <> Red)`

Comment: select only Cust_Id in subquery

Comment: try this...  Select distinct B.Cust_ID, A.Row_ID, A.Value From Cust.dbo A Left Join CustOrd.dbo B where B.Cust_ID not in (Select distinct B.Cust_ID From Cust.dbo A Left Join CustOrd.dbo B where A.Value = Red)